# Changing Recycle View Column Widths

Tags: python, kivy, recyclerview-layout

`RecycleView` is giving me some trouble, especially with changing the columns to a specific size. I coded the intended column width with a `GridLayout` above the `RecycleView`. I also made an odd way to select the whole row when one cell is selected by using modulos. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I would love other's opinions on this method.

I will eventually want to be able to delete the entire row, and then the selected data inside the JSON file. But for right now, I just want the widths appropriately sized.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

kv_string = """

ScreenManager:
    id: manager

    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.5,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y: .3
                cols:4
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Num'
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Ratings'
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Name'
                    size_hint_x: 2
                MyButton:
                    text: 'Score'
                    on_press:
                        #arrange the boxing in ascending or descending order

            RecycleView:
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in app.data]
                viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 4
                    #default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True

            ToggleButton:
                id: toggle_button
                size_hint_y: .3
                text: 'Delete Selected'
                state: 'normal'
                on_press:
                    app.data = [0]

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MyButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,1
"""
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True

        # *** This selects the whole row *** # Not sure if this is the best way.
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
            if self.index % 4 == 0:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 3)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 1:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index -1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 2:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index + 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index -1)
                return
            elif self.index % 4 == 3:
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 1)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 2)
                self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index - 3)
                return

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected

        if App.get_running_app().root.ids.toggle_button.state == 'down':
            print('Deleted', index) #Still need to add delete function
            rv.layout_manager.clear_selection() #Not working
            self.remove_widget(index) #Also not working

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleGridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    data = [] #ListProperty?

    store = JsonStore('file.json')
    store.put('Example: 1', value_1 = 'Rating: C', value_2 = 'Score: 10', value_3 = 'Name: Zack')
    store.put('Example: 2', value_1 = 'Rating: A', value_2 = 'Score: 32', value_3 = 'Name: Pete')
    store.put('Example: 3', value_1 = 'Rating: B', value_2 = 'Score: 24', value_3 = 'Name: Toby')
    store.put('Example: 4', value_1 = 'Rating: D', value_2 = 'Score: 03', value_3 = 'Name: Lars')

    x = 0

    for rows in store.keys():
        x += 1
        data.append(x)
        for row in store.get(rows):
            data.append(store.get(rows)[row])

    print(data) #shows successfully appended

    def build(self):
        root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of an ugly hack, but you can add a `refresh_view_layout` method to your `SelectableLabel` class:

```
def refresh_view_layout(self, rv, index, layout, viewport):
    mod = index % 4
    if mod == 0:
        layout['size_hint'] = (0.15, None)
    elif mod == 1:
        layout['size_hint'] = (0.225, None)
    elif mod == 2:
        layout['size_hint'] = (0.225, None)
    elif mod == 3:
        layout['size_hint'] = (0.4, None)
    super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_layout( rv, index, layout, viewport)
```

So, you can set the `size_hint` for each `SelectableLabel` to whatever you want. If you make the `size_hint_x` agree with the `size_hint_x` that is used for your `Button` column headers, I think you will get what you want.

Comment: maybe more readable: `size_hints = [(0.15, None), (0.225, None), (0.225, None), (0.4, None)]` `mod = index % 4` `layout['size_hint'] = size_hints[mod]`

Comment: @PetarLuketina Not necessarily, the comments are for short queries about the answer, and in this case the answer is for the width, it is not for the high so it is advisable that you post a question giving more detail of your intent instead of continuing to add comments :-). I will remove this comment soon because it can be considered noise.